# google apss script time - logs pm time as am

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this code:

```
  var time = new Date();
  time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT+02", "dd/MM/yy hh:mm");
```

When I use the time parameter as a file name or log it into a spreadsheet cell - it logs the hours part as am only.

For example, both 03:20 am (03:20) and 03:20 pm (15:20) will be logged as 03:20.
I am trying to log it correctly in a military time format (15:20).

How can I do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to show `03:20 pm` as `15:20`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### From:

```
hh:mm
```

#### To:

```
HH:mm
```

#### Reference:

- [Date and Time Patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

  > H: Hour in day (0-23)
  >
  > h: Hour in am/pm (1-12)

Comment: I tried it over and over for 10 times and it didn't work. Now I tried it again- and suddenly it does!
Thank you :)

Comment: For some reason I don’t see the button. Maybe because I’m viewing via phone.

Comment: not at all. I am on a desktop now and I see it. Accepted

Comment: @Yaniv Aflalo Thank you for your response.